# Execute Mysql query contains chinese character using java program

Tags: java, unicode, jdbc, character-encoding

When I execute SQL query contains chines character, the query is executed successfully. When I open the mysql query browser I could see only `????` instead of Chinese texts. If the same query executed from the mysql query browser it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try connecting with following switch

```
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://host/database?characterSetResults=UTF-8&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=yes";
```

Answer (score 0):

All encoding must be the same (there are exceptions but let's forget them): the encoding used by the DB, the connection encoding use by the Java process and the one used by the query browser. You need to change the one used by Java, since the other two seem to be OK.

Comment: I have solved the problem thank you for the reply. i have used the code given by joshi it worked fine.